# use sql in web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, web-services

I want to do some sql code run in my webservice in c#

The code is just

```
[WebMethod]
public void GetCustomers()
{
   SqlConnection MyConn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database1.mdf"].ConnectionString);
}
```

I think I got something wrong in this statement

- now my database name is:  `Database1.mdf`
- now its table name is:    `t1`

I get an error like

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at WebService1.Service1.GetCustomers() in
>   C:\Users\PRIYANK\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\WebService1\WebService1\Service1.asmx.cs:line 36

I don't know what to write in place of `[Database1.mdf]` so please write what to write in that place.

Here I place some code which might be helpful

```
[WebMethod]
public void GetCustomers()        
{
    SqlConnection MyConn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database1"].ConnectionString); 

    MyConn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = MyConn;

    cmd.CommandText = "delete from t1 where name='1'";   

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: what is `null`? have you debugged it? what is line 36?

Comment: My guess would be that there is no connection string named Database1.mdf and that is the line that it is breaking on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: What does the connection string look like in your web.config file? Can you show it here (alter the credentials please).

Comment: actually there is long code the line number 36 is connection sting which i already written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't supposed to put your data file's name in the `ConnectionString[]` element place. You should be putting your *ConnectionString*'s name. In other words, look in your `config` file to where your `<connectionStrings>` section is. You will see a `name=...` for a connection string. Use that in your:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString
```

### Example

Here is a sample from a sample config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Sales" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
       connectionString= "server=myserver;database=Products;uid=<user name>;pwd=<secure password>" />
</connectionStrings>
```

If you wanted to create a `SqlConnection` to the `Products` database, you would so this:

```
SqlConnection ProdDb = 
    new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sales"].ConnectionString);
```

Comment: thanks a lot i cant express my feelings but from last two days i am trying to find solution i am almost going mad thanks........